# Adding table header dynamically in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having some problem when trying to set table header to table layout programmatically using Android. Here is the code:

```
private void BuildTable() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM exercise";
        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (mCur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {

                TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

                TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
                tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                tv1.setTextSize(10);
                tv1.setText("ID");
                row.addView(tv1);

                TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
                tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv2.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                tv2.setTextSize(10);
                tv2.setText("Exercise Type");
                row.addView(tv2);

                TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
                tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv3.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                tv3.setTextSize(10);
                tv3.setText("Amount");
                row.addView(tv3);

                TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
                tv4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv4.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                tv4.setTextSize(10);
                tv4.setText("CheckBox");
                row.addView(tv4);

                table_layout.addView(row);

                do {
                    int cols = mCur.getColumnCount();
                    row = new TableRow(this);
                    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    for (int j = 0; j < cols + 1; j++) {
                        if (j == cols) {
                            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
                            cb.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            cb.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                            row.addView(cb);
                            final int k = mCur.getInt(mCur.getColumnIndex("exerciseID"));
                            cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    exerciseIDList.add(Integer.toString(k));
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        }

                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        tv.setTextSize(10);
                        tv.setText(mCur.getString(j));

                        row.addView(tv);

                    }
                    table_layout.addView(row);
                } while (mCur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
```

Basically I have 3 columns in my database, ID, exercise type and amount. Then when I for loop the column, I plus one so that there will be a checkbox at the end of every row.

However, after I added the tv1, tv2, tv3 and tv4 as table header, my checkbox column is missing. If I remove the table header, the checkbox column appears. I wonder which part of the code went wrong?

Comment: As I said, be consistent with your LayoutParams. For example, in many places you have `tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`. Use only the right type, don't mix them:`tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`. Also, you header row lacks its LayoutParams: `row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Comment: @Luksprog I changed it already but the checkbox column is still missing

Comment: Did you also add TableRow.LayoutParams for the first header row?

Comment: @Luksprog Yeah I changed all TableLayout into TableRow but still, the checkbox column is missing

Comment: I don't know why that columns is missing. I've re written your entire method https://gist.github.com/luksprog/8c0b59936bb77ef9a915 and it seems to work so I don't know why it fails on your part.

Comment: Okay sure thanks a lot! I will try to figure out myself. Sorry for keep troubling you! :)